# How to upgrade Ruby version when I can't figure out which program was used to install Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos

I want to upgrade `ruby` on OS X, but when I run `brew upgrade ruby` I get `Error: ruby not installed`. When I run `which ruby` I get `/usr/bin/ruby`, so I know ruby exists on my system, but I assume I the error means I didn't install it via Homebrew.

**What I Want To Know:**

1) Am I correct that the fact that `/usr/bin/ruby` exists but `brew upgrade ruby` yields `Error: ruby not installed` implies that Ruby is installed, but was installed using a tool other than Homebrew?

2) If so, how can I figure out how/where Ruby was installed on my system?

3) How should I approach upgrading Ruby?

Comment: What I do is use brew to install rvm and rvm to install ruby. That way I know where I stand. :)

Comment: I tried using rvm to upgrade Ruby via `rvm install ruby-2.7.0` but that led to a slew of other errors. When you say you use rvm to install ruby, do you mean that you used rvm to install ruby in the first place? Or just to upgrade it, the way I was doing?

Comment: Well you cannot upgrade the built in Mac OSX ruby. So you need to install another ruby somehow. I like rvm for doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I correct that the fact that `/usr/bin/ruby` exists but `brew upgrade ruby` yields `Error: ruby not installed` implies that Ruby is installed, but was installed using a tool other than Homebrew?

Yes.

> If so, how can I figure out how/where Ruby was installed on my system?

It comes with OS X (for now). Apple plans to deprecate this though, see [here](https://tidbits.com/2019/06/25/apple-to-deprecate-scripting-languages-in-future-versions-of-macos/).

> How should I approach upgrading Ruby?

This is opinion-based, but I would manage it with brew, which means you need to `brew install ruby` it as well. To make sure you use the `brew install`ed ruby instead of the system ruby, you can add something like add:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:${PATH}
```

to your `~/.bash_profile`. Specifically, you will want to add (a) the path where `brew` will provide ruby and all its related executables, and (b) the path where executables installed via `gem` will exist.

For (a), look at the output of `brew info ruby`, for instance I get:

```
...

If you need to have ruby first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

...
```

Hence the addition of `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin` to the path. If you `ls` that directory, you'll see not only the `ruby` executable but also `irb`, `gem`, `bundle`, `rake`, and a few others. So when you run `bundle install` or `gem install`, that's what'll get used.

For (b), you need to know where installed gem executables get put. The `gem env` command helps you there:

```
$ gem env | grep 'EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY'
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
```

Hence the addition of the second path, `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin` to my `$PATH` in my `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks! If I've already been using the system ruby, then install the brew version and, what implications does that have for the packages I installed before and the new ones I install now? Is it the case that gems installed with the system ruby are installed in one place, the gems installed with the brew ruby are installed in another place, but for the purposes of using the gems it doesn't make a difference? What would happen if I install a version of a gem with the brew ruby for which there's already an older version installed via the system ruby?

Comment: You are ranging way beyond the original question. In my opinion what you asked is answered.

Comment: @matt I approved the original answer.

Comment: Then if this leads to a new question, ask it as a new question.

Comment: @Amit Could you explain the two paths you appended to your path variable? ie what's the difference between `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin` and `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin`?

Comment: @gkeenley updated my answer to explain those two paths.

Comment: Perfect explanation, I appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to help! 

Answer (score 2):

Using `which ruby`, you've already found that ruby is installed to your path at `/usr/bin/ruby`.

There's a high likelihood this is a symlink to the actual location of the executable.
You can follow it via `readlink /usr/bin/ruby`. Hopefully, it's in a folder that makes it obvious what installed it. If not, there's not much hope of figuring that out, but at least you know where all the files are to clean it up.

I'd then install [RVM](https://rvm.io/) and start fresh.

Comment: It's often the case that when RVM is installed it's not *completely* installed. You need to ensure that the RVM path is in your `$PATH`, which it may not be. Check your `~/.bashrc` or whatever shell RC file you're using.

Comment: Hi iCodeSometime, thanks! When I run `readlink /usr/bin/ruby`, nothing displays. How would I get it to display the symlink info?

Comment: It must not be a symlink then. afaik all package managers install via symlinks, so I'm certain Amit Kumar Gupta's answer is correct. I'd initially believed that the OS version would be installed under `/bin`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Regardless, this process has helped me multiple times in similar situations :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your insight. Re "that doesn't seem to be the case", am I correct that this implies either 1) OS X doesn't install its version of ruby via symlink, or 2) it does, but this isn't the system version of ruby? If so, any idea what `/usr/bin/ruby` could be..?

Comment: I'm not with my mac at the moment, but my guess is that the default ruby install on OSX has the full executable, rather than a symlink, at `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: Ok cool, I'll leave another comment here if I find out anything different. Thanks again!